# Where is the "Load symbols lazily" debugging option in XCode4?

Tags: xcode4

My breakpoints are not working in XCode4. To fix this in XCode3 I turned off the "Load symbols lazily" option, I can't find a similar option in XCode4...

Comment: I'm seeing this too, and it's frustrating.  my breakpoints work at first but i want to disable them until a certain point and they won't work if i do :(

Comment: Hey are you able to solve the problem ? I am getting same problem.

Answer (score 5):

There is no Load Symbols Lazily option in Xcode 4.

The Breakpoints button in the project window toolbar toggles running/debugging your program. Xcode initially sets the button for running, which disables your breakpoints. For your breakpoints to be enabled, the Breakpoints button should look like the following:

[image: Breakpoints Button]

Answer (score 0):

In earlier Xcode version find Xcode -> Preferences -> Debugging tab. Uncheck **Load symbols lazily** if checked. It seems to be dropped from Xcode 4. 
Have a look at this post [click here](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2337)

This worked for me.