# Xcode4 : Why my breakpoints are not working in Xcode4?

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4

I am unable to debug my project as the breakpoints are not working.

I have enabled breakpoint option but still its not helping me.

I found some links but they are for the [Xcode3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64790/why-arent-my-breakpoints-working-in-xcode)

And for Xcode4 I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280137/where-is-the-load-symbols-lazily-debugging-option-in-xcode4) site but it doesn't have any solution.

What should I do ?

Comment: Check out [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009984-CH3-SW1) Apple's document. It may help you to proceed with Xcode4.

Comment: Your question isn't answerable with the detail you provided. Can you elaborate? What have you tried? What are your settings/configuration details? Scheme, build configuration, etc. Have you customized anything? Can you get it to work with a new, plain project?

Comment: @Heena: Did you try restarting Xcode or may be restarting Mac?

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Scheme drop box
2. Click on Edit Scheme

[image]

2. Click on Run YOURAPP.app tab on the left

   - Set Build Configuration to DEBUG
   - Set Debugger to LLDB
3. Enable breakpoints and Run the app

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ran face first into this problem after updating to iOS SDK 6.1.  After a few hours of swearing and digging through settings, it seems to only happen when using LLDB.  Switching to GDB has bestowed upon me the ability to use breakpoints again.  FWIW I've had other issues with LLDB not correctly following vtable pointers.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebooting your device. 
I had the same problem with Xcode4; although, I seem to remember it working before upgrading my phone to 6.1. 
Anyhow, the suggestion [here](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2337) to reboot my device solved the problem. Breakpoints are again working for me.